# Как нажать на кнопку на сайте через Python?

Tags: python, парсер

Есть сайт, на котором некоторые элементы страницы недоступны до нажатия на кнопку. Адрес при нажатии при этом не меняется, поэтому нельзя просто перейти на другую страницу. Как это сделать? Какие библиотеки нужны?

Comment: Нет баллов на коммент, поэтому так. Это должно помочь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869225/python-clicking-a-button-on-a-webpage

Answer (score 1):

Для подобных целей есть [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/).

Вот небольшой пример авторизации в вк.

```python
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

VK_ROOT_URL = "https://vk.com/"

class TestFunc(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get(VK_ROOT_URL)

    def login(self, username, password):
        email_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id("index_email")
        email_field.send_keys(username)
        sleep(5)

        password_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id("index_pass")
        password_field.send_keys(password)
        sleep(5)

        login_button = self.driver.find_element_by_id("index_login_button")
        login_button.click()

if __name__ == __main__:
   username = 'username'
   password = 'password'
   TestFunc().login(username, password)
```

Для марса у селенитам есть такая функция как get_attribute("outerHTML"), которая возвращает HTML. В вашем распоряжении есть большая [документация](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/index.html).